# How to using lib assets_audio_player with flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I can using assets_audio_player for app with firebase url but when I open in Web, it can not open audio . How I can implement assets_audio_player with Web.

Comment: it might be cors problem

Comment: I know asset_audio_play supports both web and mobile, but there is no example code for using it like on mobile. But when using the code of the mobile phone, it is completely unable to play the sound from the network url. When running on the web also can't debug, I don't know where is wrong?

Comment: cross origin might be the problem because firebase url doesn't have cors enabled Open console in dev tools and see if there is any error for cors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.